# Setting thresholds via smartd.conf

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance-monitoring, smart

We currently use smartd to monitor SMART health on our disks.  I would like to set the 'thresholds' that smartd uses to report.

For example:

```
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       9
```

I would like to be able to set a threshold for these two attributes to only report if they are above 10.  I haven't been able to find a way to set this via smartd.conf, and I'm also not looking to actually shutdown the daemon.

Has anyone ever tried this, or know how I might be able to accomplish this better then throwing a script into cron.hourly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending the HUP signal to smartd will cause it to reload the config without killing the daemon.

Although, that doesn't help you in your quest for what you seek.

You can't change the threshold values on a S.M.A.R.T. disk, as they're set by the manufacturer at build time.

You will have to resort to a a cron job that polls the values using smartctl, and compares them to the thresholds you want.